# Cannot parse MySql TImestamp with JSON

Tags: mysql, json, parsing, serialization, timestamp

While trying to parse the following JSON string:

```
{
    marketplaceId:"MKPL",
    asin:"ASIN1",
    sourceTimestamp:2013-03-19T23:38:24.054Z,
    orderId:"ORD1",
    vendorId:"SUPR1",
    warehouseId:"SEA8",
    inventoryOwnerGroup:376,
    lastUpdatedAt:2013-03-19T23:38:23.919Z,
    isHighConfidence:true,
    quantityArriving:2,
    expectedDeliveryDate:2013-03-19T23:38:23.919Z
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.sql.Timestamp out of VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.amazon.freshwombat.po.PurchaseRecord["lastUpdatedAt"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.TimestampDeserializer.deserialize(TimestampDeserializer.java:28)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.TimestampDeserializer.deserialize(TimestampDeserializer.java:19)
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON doesn't support the concept of "dates". It only supports [simple data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) like strings, numbers, arrays, booleans, etc. So, represent your dates as strings. E.g.:

```
lastUpdatedAt: "2013-03-19T23:38:23.919Z",
```

You'll have to do the actual date parsing with other JavaScript facilities/third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Jackson** for JSon to Object conversion you must specify the `DateFormat` a `mapper` instance should use in order to generate Date from String values that represents a date or `timestamp`.

In the case of the of a (`mysql`) `timestamp` :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(format)
Entity entity = mapper.readValue("{ }", Entity.class);
```

So closely following the advices of @SimpleCoder and with this snippet i guess you shouldn't have problems.